# How to link QnA Maker answer in Adaptive Card=

Tags: json, botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker, adaptive-cards

I'm rather new with these technologies so bear with me. I have successfully deployed Bot Framework and linked QnA Maker to it. I am using Adaptive Card for first response and i want images in that adaptive card to (when clicked) to generate answer from QnA Maker. How can i link these images to generate QnA Maker answer? Is there a way to just give it URL that would trigger QnA Maker?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: If i understand correctly what you mean by channel, i am currently just testing out in Visual Studio + Bot Emulator. Later purpose is to webchat, direct line and teams channels.

Comment: Stevie's answer will not work in Teams. See my blog post for more info: https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the data property in your Adaptive Card to send a message payload to the Bot, which would then trigger the QnA answer.

For example, in the data property, if you put something like 'How do I upload a file', so when the image is clicked, the payload will be 'How do I upload a file' and will be sent to the Bot, where the QnA service should respond in kind with the correct answer.

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "style": "Person",
                            "url": "${creator.profileImage}",
                            "size": "Small",
                            "selectAction": {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "id": "image",
                                "title": "image",
                                "data": "show me the text 'image'"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "auto"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2"
}
```